# User-scoped "personal" list fields?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

Is it possible in SharePoint 2010 (Foundation) to have a list with columns:  A, B, and "My Notes".  Where columns A and B are consistently displayed the same for all users, but the "My Notes" column is user-scoped?  Meaning I'd only see *my* notes and you'd only see *your* notes?

I don't mind building custom content types, etc. Perhaps introduce another "hidden" list that contains a User ID and the associated note, then somehow look up and display only the note for the current user/list?

I am trying to break down the problem of building my own "Rating" system (thumbs up / thumbs down) for custom list items.  I believe that user-scoped fields (e.g. the "My Notes" example) could be one component of such a system.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Mikey,

the way you describe it, is not possible. But you can make use of the tags and notes features that shipped with SharePoint 2010, and they can even be made private.

Comment: Thanks Bas, perhaps I was assuming too much -- what is the architecture of the sharepoint server 2010 "content rating" feature?  Functionally it is very similar to what I'd like to do except instead of 5 stars, "thumbs up / thumbs down".